# PHP: How to read POST body with Transfer-Encoding: chunked, no Content-Length

Tags: php, apache, http-headers

I am writing a service to receive data from an energy monitoring device in my house. The only way the device can push data is by using an HTTP `POST`, with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, and no `Content-Length`, and the data as XML in the request body.

I would like to be able to read this data in a PHP script (behind Apache) and store it in my database.

It appears that the most correct way to read the HTTP request body in PHP these days is to open and read `php://input`. However, comments from users on PHP's website indicate (and my testing confirms), that if no `Content-Length` header is specified by the client, `php://input` returns no data (even if there is data being sent by the client in chunked encoding).

Is there an alternate way to get access to the request body? Can I configure Apache (with .htaccess) to decode the chunked data and call my script once it gets it all, and include `Content-Length`? Or configure PHP so it will be able to handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of PHP?  I recall this being specific to fastCGI implementations and not mod_php.  Technically they are following HTTP 1.1 specs.  For mod_fcgid you could look into this [patch](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53332).  Ref: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60826

Comment: Ah, I am using PHP 5.6.5 with FastCGI. I will try changing to not-fast-CGI (my web host lets me choose) and see what happens; I'll report back shortly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Might as well write this as an answer I suppose.

The issue you describe is documented here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60826

Highlights from the thread:

> So here is what I found. If you send chunked http request but do not
>   send the content-length (as we should do using HTTP 1.1 protocol) the
>   body part of the request is empty (php://input returns nothing). This
>   result remains valid for the following configuration where PHP runs
>   via FastCGI :
>
> The same configuration with PHP running as mod_php is fine, the body
>   request is available through php://input.

And

> Essentially, PHP is following the spec, and not reading beyond the
>   FastCGI  CONTENT_LENGTH header value - so correct fixes are
>   necessarily above PHP, in the  FastCGI or web server implementation.

**Possible Workarounds:**

0) Use httpd with mod_php

1) Use a different web server.

2) Look at patches for mod_fcgid

3) Maybe (not recommended) flip `always_populate_raw_post_data` and see if there is anything in [$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php)

Comment: Thanks. My web host (Dreamhost) lets me switch between "CGI" and "FastCGI" when selecting which version of PHP to use for a domain, so I switched it to CGI (it was FastCGI), but `php://input` still doesn't seem to contain anything.

Comment: Yeah.  Unfortunately the two primary, call them handlers, are CGI (common gateway interface) or DSO (Dynamic Shared Object).  Both fastCGI and CGI will be impacted by the issue.  If choosing over CGI and fastCGI use fastCGI.  As I understand it you would need to use mod_php (the DSO) with apache, or use another server perhaps like nginx... Or maybe that [patched mod_fcgid](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53332) with apache.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Since none of these are options on my shared hosting account, I will have to figure out something else instead. Thanks for your help, I'll mark your answer as accepted in case anyone else runs across this.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue recently with Apache 2.4.58 and PHP 8.2.15 (empty `$_POST` when the `Content-Encoding: chunked` header is persent), and fixed it by adding the following line in the Apache configuration:

```
SetEnv proxy-sendcl 1
```

This configuration is related to [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html), which is used to handle PHP FPM. The line above should be added near `ProxyPass` (something similar is seen in the [mod_proxy docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#envsettings)):

```
<Location "/buggyappserver/">
  ProxyPass "http://buggyappserver:7001/foo/"
  SetEnv proxy-sendcl 1
</Location>
```

Or as in my case (in **Amazon Lightsail / Bitnami**) near the `SetHandler "proxy:..."` directive in `/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/php-fpm.conf`, like this:

```
<IfDefine USE_PHP_FPM>
  <Proxy "unix:/opt/bitnami/php/var/run/www.sock|fcgi://www-fpm" timeout=300>
  </Proxy>
  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
      SetEnv proxy-sendcl 1
      SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://www-fpm"
    </If>
  </FilesMatch>
</IfDefine>
```

Related Apache issues:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63366
- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57087

But since you asked about `php://input`, I will add that according to the [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input):

> `php://input` is not available in POST requests with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` if `enable_post_data_reading` option is enabled.

So be sure to check that option too.