# Reading php://input from a request that is using Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Tags: php, apache, request, debian, fpm

For the first time in my long career, I am struggling to retrieve the input body of a RESTful Event Notification when the request is using `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` (with `Content-Type: application/json`)

`$_POST` is obviously empty due to `Content-Type: application/json`

`file_get_contents('php://input')` is always empty, hoping someone can explain why; is Apache not passing this through to php-fpm?

Attempting to retrieve the chunks using `fopen` also fails?

```php
$hSource = fopen('php://input', 'r');
$body = '';

while (!feof($hSource)) {
    $chunk = fread($hSource, 1024);
    $body .= $chunk;
}
fclose($hSource);
```

Is this a dead-end or am I going about this entirely wrong? I'm aware that if I have the service add the Content-Length header then all of the above would actually be working fine but they stress this 5-minute task would take them months to get across the line.

Apache `downgrade-1.0` (ew...) also doesn't force them to send their requests as HTTP/1.0.

Thanks

Comment: Using `mod_php` or `php-fpm`?

Comment: `php-fpm` thanks @Phil

Comment: Have you seen this post? [PHP: How to read POST body with Transfer-Encoding: chunked, no Content-Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30924004/php-how-to-read-post-body-with-transfer-encoding-chunked-no-content-length)

Comment: I have, that confirms it's a dead-end for me as we can't make any of those changes, that answer being 6 years old had me hoping for some evolution in the matter.

Comment: If you follow the links to the PHP bug, there's a comment right at the end from April this year... _"Apache's bug for this is here https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57087 and has apparently been fixed in Apache/2.4.47"_. The Apache BugZilla site seems down right now so can't check the details

Comment: Some other comments in the PHP list suggest this isn't a problem when using NGINX and the _chunkin_ module

Comment: Thank you Phil, we're on 2.4.38 lol. You can post that as an answer for some rep if you like :)

Comment: You're in a better place to test and verify. Feel free to self-answer once you've got results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my scenario, this is due to the bug pointed out by @Phil in the comments

This specifically affects php-fpm, and for most users they can upgrade Apache to 2.4.46+.

**Bug:** https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57087

**If you're a Debian user**, as of writing this; there isn't an official *stable* release for 2.4.46 yet, and it is in testing phase as shown [here](https://packages.qa.debian.org/a/apache2.html). We fell-back back to mod_php instead while we wait for a stable release, others may be inclined to use Nginx instead.

**EDIT** Debian has now released a stable version where this is fixed, it only took them 10 years, and the timing couldn't have been better.

Comment: Had same issue now.  took week to figure out.   changed to mod_php and now all working fine when using Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Comment: @KarmanDeLange I completely feel your pain, glad its sorted