# Large post data is lost when submitting to new web server from Android

Tags: php, android, apache

I have iOS and Android mobile apps that submit data to a PHP web application. I'm moving the web application from a server running CentOS 7, Apache 2.4.6 and PHP 7.3.33 (mod_php) to a server running Alma Linux 9, Apache 2.4.57 and PHP 8.0.30 (PHP-FPM). With the new server, only when submitting from Android, post data larger than about 7800 bytes is not recognized by PHP; the `$_POST` array is empty and `php://input` is empty. A smaller submission is fine and a submission of any length from iOS is fine.

On the Android side, I'm using `HttpURLConnection` and `outputStream`. I think the data is encoded and submitted correctly because it submits fine to the old server and a small amount of data submits fine to the new server. The Android app hasn't changed, only the web server.

On the web server side, I've set `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` much larger than they need to be in /etc/php.ini. I know these are working because if I set them too low, I get a PHP error in the Apache error log ("POST Content-Length exceeds the limit..."). Interestingly, this is not triggered when submitting too much data from Android, so apparently the post data is lost or discarded before PHP does that check. I tried using tcpdump and it looks like all the data is reaching the server either way.

Similarly, I checked the `LimitRequestBody` directive in Apache. I am not setting that, so it should be defaulting to 1 GB, and should log an error if that's the problem.

I tested sending various sizes of data from Android; 7800 bytes or less succeeds and 7900 bytes or more fails. The Apache access log shows a single POST request with a status of 200, so it's not getting redirected, and the Android app receives that status code and the response text from the web server, whether it succeeds or fails. Nothing is added to the Apache error log when it fails. The only difference I see is that no post data is available to my script.

I've tested with devices running Android 7, Android 12 and Android 14.

I would expect this to be a server issue since that's the part that has changed, but I don't know of any server settings that would depend on the client operating system.

Maybe the Android app is encoding the data in some nonstandard way that the old server permitted but the new server doesn't. But when I change the post data to a very simple "test=aaaaaa" with 7900 a's, it still fails. With 7800 a's it works fine.

I'm normally submitting through SSL, but I tried submitting as plain text on port 80 and that didn't make a difference.

Maybe it's a matter of the time needed to process the post data rather than the length of the data, but it doesn't seem like any timeout is happening because the app receives the response from the server. And it seems really consistent depending only on the length of the data.

I have always run PHP as an Apache module before now, so maybe there is some change I need to make to the PHP setup. I haven't changed anything in /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf. Also, most of the web searches I've done about this bring up posts about Nginx. I see some Nginx config files on my server, but I don't know what it is and am not aware of using it. I know I'm using Apache because that's where I set up my virtual hosts, logging, etc.

Does anyone have more ideas for me?

UPDATE: Here's the Android code that submits the data. I'm using Android SDK version 33. This works fine when submitting to the old web server.

```
val data = "test=" + "a".repeat(7900)
var request: HttpURLConnection? = null
int responseCode = 0;
try {
    request = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    responseCode = request.getResponseCode();
} catch (e: IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    this.error = "bad_request"
    return false
}

request.connectTimeout = (this.timeoutLength * 1000).roundToInt()
if ((method == "POST")&&(data != null)) {
    try {
        request.doOutput = true
        request.setChunkedStreamingMode(data.length)
        val outputStream = request.outputStream
        val outputStreamWriter = OutputStreamWriter(outputStream)
        val outputWriter = BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter)
        var next = 0
        var chunkLength = 512
        val totalLength = data.length
        this.publishProgress(0, totalLength)
        while (next < totalLength) {
            if (next + chunkLength > totalLength) {
                chunkLength = totalLength - next
            }
            outputWriter.write(data, next, chunkLength)
            this.publishProgress(next, 0)
            next += chunkLength
        }
        outputWriter.close()
        outputStreamWriter.close()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        this.error = "bad_post_data"
        return false
    }
}

try {
    this.publishProgress(0, request.contentLength)
    val inputStream = request.inputStream
    val chunk = ByteArray(4096)
    var chunkSize = -1
    while (inputStream.read(chunk).also { chunkSize = it } != -1) {
        try {
            this.response.write(chunk, 0, chunkSize)
            publishProgress(this.response.size(), 0)
        } catch (e: OutOfMemoryError) {
            this.error = "out_of_memory"
            inputStream.close()
            return false
        }
    }
    inputStream.close()
    if (this.response.size() == 0) {
        this.error = "bad_response"
        return false
    }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    if (e.toString().contains("UnknownHostException")) {
        this.error = "offline"
    } else if (e.toString().contains("SocketTimeoutException")) {
        this.error = "timeout"
    } else {
        this.error = "bad_response"
    }
    return false
} finally {
    request.disconnect()
}
```

And at the top of the PHP script this submits to:

```
$rawdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
error_log($rawdata); // [empty]
error_log(count($_POST)); // 0
```

Comment: For identifying problems with a server it is best to be able to reproduce the problem with a totally different client. Have you tried e.g. to use `curl` to create an identical request? If that triggers the same problem you can be sure that the server is the problem and turn inside out on the server and it's configuration.

Comment: @Robert The problem does not happen when submitting data from the iOS app. I can try curl. EDIT: No problem from curl, either.

Comment: Then your Android code is most likely the problem. Which HTTP library and version do you use? Also please post the code where you build and send the problematic POST request.

Comment: Thanks, I just added the Android submission code and the PHP receiving code.

Answer (score 1):

I was focusing on the server side, but with Robert's suggestion to focus on the Android side, I found the problem, with this line:

```
request.setChunkedStreamingMode(data.length)
```

The Android documentation says "not all HTTP servers support this mode," so it makes sense that the problem would start when changing web servers. And it makes sense that a "chunking" functionality would fail only when the data exceeded a certain size. I don't think it was doing anything useful anyway since the argument should be a chunk size and I had it set to the complete size.

Anyway, I replaced that line with this and now all submissions work from Android again:

```
request.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", data.length.toString())
```

I'm still looking for a way to support the "chunked streaming" from the server side so previous app versions can still work. I'll leave this answer unaccepted in case someone else knows how to do that.

This post explains the problem well (it's an Apache problem and doesn't happen with mod_php):

[PHP: How to read POST body with Transfer-Encoding: chunked, no Content-Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30924004/php-how-to-read-post-body-with-transfer-encoding-chunked-no-content-length)

This Apache bug report says it was fixed in Apache 2.4.47, so I don't know why I'm having the problem with Apache 2.4.57:

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57087

I have confirmed that when a client doesn't use chunked mode, PHP receives a Content-Length header even if the client didn't set it; but when my previous app versions enable chunked mode, PHP receives no Content-Length header, which apparently leads it to not read the content.