php and http encoding chuncked post request
I'm using vscode in Ubuntu OS 64 to use an esp32 as client from server running in the ubuntu. The esp32 send POST request with encoding chunked and I'm trying to get this data using php. But I don't see anything, I tried with
file_get_contents('php://input');
but there is no data. Im using apache2 2.4.58 and apache 8.3.6
I never used chunked encoding in http request and maybe I missed some configs in apache2
I tried reading the input and saving the POST request to a file, but there is nothing in the file..is empty. I know that the data is sent I already check this with wireshark but can't get those values with php.
Regards
Gastón

Could be the same issue as here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30924257/1427878 - "If you send chunked http request but do not send the content-length (as we should do using HTTP 1.1 protocol) the body part of the request is empty (php://input returns nothing)" - does your client set Content-Length?

@C3roe Chunked encoding is generally used when the data is generated dynamically, so the length isn't known when you send the headers. The last comment in the bug report says it was fixed in Apache 2.4.47.

I found this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30924004/php-how-to-read-post-body-with-transfer-encoding-chunked-no-content-length
the same problem. I disable enable_post_data_rading. I also intalled php fpm but still unable to get input data from post request chunlk encoding. How to config apache to receive post request data?
